# Office.js: AddImage() not working in Excel online version

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm trying to add a new image from an Excel adding using Office.js.

That's my code:

```
    image = activeWorkSheet.shapes.addImage(imageBase64);
    await context.sync();

    // set some image properties
```

This is failing with the error:

```
RichApi.Error: This operation is not implemented.
    at new c (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-web-16.00.js:24:287800)
    at a.e.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-web-16.00.js:24:348351)
    at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-web-16.00.js:24:346456
```

I also tried using "Imagecoercion", but this seems to be unsupported, and in fact, I'm not able to use it: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/648.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The Shapes APIs require Excel.js version 1.9. Is your build of Excel recent enough to support that version? See [Excel API Requirement Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets).

Comment: Hi Rick, this is the build number I see from Office Online in the about section: 16.0.12311.37950.

Comment: I've also opened a github issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/841